No Output from Windows x64 Assembly Code Using `CreateProcessA` and Related API Calls
I've been working on an assembly program for process management in Windows x64 using NASM and MinGW. The goal is to use CreateProcessA to run cmd.exe, wait for it to complete, and then retrieve the exit code. However, the program isn't producing any output, and I'm unable to determine why.
Here's the latest version of my code:
section .data
    ; Command line to execute
    cmd_line db "C:\Windows\System32\cmd.exe", 0

    ; Log messages
    create_process_msg db "Creating process...", 10, 0
    process_done_msg db "Process completed with exit code: %d", 10, 0
    error_msg db "Error: Could not create process.", 10, 0

section .bss
    ; Reserve space for structures
    sin resb 68                     ; STARTUPINFO structure (size 68 bytes)
    pi resb 24                      ; PROCESS_INFORMATION structure (size 24 bytes)
    exit_code resd 1                ; to store the process exit code

section .text
    extern CreateProcessA, WaitForSingleObject, GetExitCodeProcess, printf, ExitProcess, CloseHandle
    global main

main:
    ; Zero out the STARTUPINFO structure
    lea rcx, [rel sin]
    xor rax, rax
    mov rdi, 68                     ; size of STARTUPINFO
    rep stosb

    ; Set the cb member to the size of the structure
    mov dword [rel sin], 68         ; STARTUPINFO.cb = 68

    ; Print message for creating the process
    lea rcx, [rel create_process_msg]
    call printf

    ; Preserve registers before calling CreateProcessA
    push r12
    push r13
    push r10
    push r11

    ; Call CreateProcessA
    lea rcx, [rel cmd_line]         ; lpCommandLine
    xor rdx, rdx                    ; lpApplicationName (NULL)
    xor r8, r8                      ; lpProcessAttributes (NULL)
    xor r9, r9                      ; lpThreadAttributes (NULL)
    mov r10d, 1                     ; bInheritHandles = TRUE
    mov r11d, 0                     ; dwCreationFlags = 0
    lea r12, [rel sin]              ; lpStartupInfo
    lea r13, [rel pi]               ; lpProcessInformation
    sub rsp, 40                     ; Align stack for Windows x64 calling convention
    call CreateProcessA
    add rsp, 40                     ; Restore stack alignment

    ; Restore preserved registers
    pop r11
    pop r10
    pop r13
    pop r12

    ; Check if process creation was successful
    test rax, rax
    jz process_creation_failed

    ; Wait for the process to complete
    mov rcx, [rel pi + 0]           ; pi.hProcess
    mov rdx, -1                     ; INFINITE timeout
    call WaitForSingleObject

    ; Get the exit code of the process
    mov rcx, [rel pi + 0]           ; pi.hProcess
    lea rdx, [rel exit_code]        ; lpExitCode
    call GetExitCodeProcess

    ; Print the exit code
    mov rsi, [rel exit_code]
    lea rdi, [rel process_done_msg]
    xor rax, rax
    call printf

    ; Close process and thread handles
    mov rcx, [rel pi + 0]           ; pi.hProcess
    call CloseHandle
    mov rcx, [rel pi + 8]           ; pi.hThread
    call CloseHandle

    ; Exit the program
    xor ecx, ecx
    call ExitProcess

process_creation_failed:
    ; Print error message
    lea rcx, [rel error_msg]
    call printf

    ; Exit with error code
    mov ecx, 1
    call ExitProcess

Debugging Attempts:

Relocation Errors: I originally encountered relocation errors, which were resolved by removing the rel references.
Register Overwriting: I suspected rcx was being overwritten, so I added checks to preserve it, but the issue persists.
Changing .bss Section: I tried replacing resb with resq in the .bss section, which didn't resolve the issue.
Error Handling: I added error messages to check if CreateProcessA fails, but even these aren't printed.
Stack and Alignment: I made sure to follow the Windows x64 calling convention and align the stack, but no success.

Observations:

The program compiles and links without errors, but nothing is printed to the console.
Even when I deliberately induce an error condition (like failing to create a process), the error message isn't displayed.
The program seems to execute silently, and the lack of any output makes debugging challenging

Compile program

nasm -f win64 EX.asm -o EX.o
gcc -m64 -o EX EX.o -lkernel32 -lmsvcrt
.\EX.exe

Environment

OS: Windows 10 x64
Assembler: NASM
Linker: Mingw-w64

What could be causing this assembly code to produce no output at all? Is there something specific about using CreateProcessA and related API calls in NASM for Windows x64 that I might be missing?
Thank you in advance for your help and suggestions!

Found the following problems with the code:

Your Zero out the STARTUPINFO structure is already broken because you swapped rcx and rdi. Of course .bss starts out zeroed so you don't even need that.
You should set up the shadow space in the prologue. As is, only the CreateProcess is called properly, the other functions do not have the shadow space and get a misaligned stack. This already affects the first printf.
As per calling convention only the first 4 arguments are passed in registers, the rest should go on the stack.
You got the application name and the command line swapped and completely missed the lpEnvironment and lpCurrentDirectory arguments.
Printing the exit code uses the wrong registers (linux convention) and the wrong size.
Windows uses CR LF for end of line.
Not technically a problem but while r10 and r11 are indeed caller saved since you don't use them you don't need to save them. r12 and r13 are automatically preserved across calls so you don't need to save them either. Also, saving registers out of order without reason is bad practice (even though you got the pops matching properly).

Note that this should be linked into a console application and possibly run from a command window to see any output.
Here is a suggested fix:
section .data
    ; Command line to execute
    cmd_line db "C:\Windows\System32\cmd.exe", 0

    ; Log messages
    create_process_msg db "Creating process...", 13, 10, 0
    process_done_msg db "Process completed with exit code: %d", 13, 10, 0
    error_msg db "Error: Could not create process.", 13, 10, 0

section .bss
    ; Reserve space for structures
    sin resb 68                     ; STARTUPINFO structure (size 68 bytes)
    pi resb 24                      ; PROCESS_INFORMATION structure (size 24 bytes)
    exit_code resd 1                ; to store the process exit code

section .text
    extern CreateProcessA, WaitForSingleObject, GetExitCodeProcess, printf, ExitProcess, CloseHandle
    global main

main:
    sub rsp, 88 ; shadow space + 6 args + aligment

    ; Set the cb member to the size of the structure
    mov dword [rel sin], 68         ; STARTUPINFO.cb = 68

    ; Print message for creating the process
    lea rcx, [rel create_process_msg]
    call printf

    ; Call CreateProcessA
    xor ecx, ecx                    ; lpApplicationName (NULL)
    lea rdx, [rel cmd_line]         ; lpCommandLine
    xor r8, r8                      ; lpProcessAttributes (NULL)
    xor r9, r9                      ; lpThreadAttributes (NULL)

    mov dword [rsp + 32], 1         ; bInheritHandles = TRUE
    mov [rsp + 40], ecx             ; dwCreationFlags = 0
    mov [rsp + 48], ecx             ; lpEnvironment
    mov [rsp + 56], ecx             ; lpCurrentDirectory
    lea rax, [rel sin]
    mov [rsp + 64], rax             ; lpStartupInfo
    lea rax, [rel pi]
    mov [rsp + 72], rax             ; lpProcessInformation
    call CreateProcessA

    ; Check if process creation was successful
    test rax, rax
    jz process_creation_failed

    ; Wait for the process to complete
    mov rcx, [rel pi + 0]           ; pi.hProcess
    mov rdx, -1                     ; INFINITE timeout
    call WaitForSingleObject

    ; Get the exit code of the process
    mov rcx, [rel pi + 0]           ; pi.hProcess
    lea rdx, [rel exit_code]        ; lpExitCode
    call GetExitCodeProcess

    ; Print the exit code
    lea rcx, [rel process_done_msg]
    mov edx, [rel exit_code]
    call printf

    ; Close process and thread handles
    mov rcx, [rel pi + 0]           ; pi.hProcess
    call CloseHandle
    mov rcx, [rel pi + 8]           ; pi.hThread
    call CloseHandle

    ; Exit the program
    xor ecx, ecx
    call ExitProcess

process_creation_failed:
    ; Print error message
    lea rcx, [rel error_msg]
    call printf

    ; Exit with error code
    mov ecx, 1
    call ExitProcess


Thank you for your response. I implemented the code you provided, and it successfully prints the log messages, but unfortunately, the process creation still fails. The error code returned by GetLastError is 998, which corresponds to ERROR_NOACCESS ("Invalid access to memory location").

I double-checked all parameters passed to CreateProcessA and confirmed they are set up as expected. Also, I tried different values for lpCommandLine (including the path to cmd.exe and notepad.exe), but the issue persists.

The program outputs "Creating process..." and then "Error: Could not create process." followed by "Error Code: 998".
I would greatly appreciate any further insights or suggestions on what could be causing this issue. Thank you for your help so far!

Check the latest updated code

Works fine here.
